# Struts 1.2 Servlet Filter and web.xml filtering url-pattern

Tags: xss, servlet-filters, url-pattern

I have a URL in the following form...

```
 htts://www.mysite/admin/userprofile.do
```

Using a servlet filter I want to prevent certain things in part of the URL. Using the following in web.xml...

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

With an appropriate servlet-filter how could I change url-pattern to only manage the /admin/ portion of the URL (this is an old app that for whatever reason allows an XSS injection only in that portion). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this like below :

```
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```